# going back and forth between screens causes double navigation bars

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For this project, I installed

```
npm install --save react-navigation@1.5.2
```

because later versions of react navigation was throwing an error.  I just had one navigation bar when I started the application, but when I started going back and forth between the screens, I started getting two navigation bar. My code is extremely simple, I have two buttons on my first screen (app.js). Below is the image:

[image]

The second button navigates to another page called "AvailableService" and then I have a  ListView inside availableService screen that navigates to a different screen called secondactivity. I think this causes a loop and causes to appear two navigation bar on the screen.

Below is my code and images for first screen and then availableserviceScreen and Second Activity screen:

App.js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MissionActivity from './Modules/MissionActivity';
import AvailableService from './Modules/Availableservice';

type Props = {};
 class MainActivity extends Component<Props> {

  OpenMissionActivityFunction = () =>
  {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Mission');

  }

  OpenAvailableServicesFunction = () =>
  {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('AvailableService');

  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
      <View style={styles.toolbar}>
         <Image 
              resizeMode='contain'
              style={styles.toolbarTitle} 
             source={require('./images/Logo.jpg')} />
      </View>
      <View>
       <Image 
        style={styles.title} 
     source={require('./images/test.png')} />
     </View>

     <View style={styles.searchButton}>
     <Button onPress = { this.OpenMissionActivityFunction } title = 'Mission'/>

    </View>
    <View style={styles.searchButton}>
      <Button onPress = { this.OpenAvailableServicesFunction } title = 'Available Services'/>
    </View>

   </View>
    );
  }
}
export default ActivityProject = StackNavigator(
  {
    First: { screen: MainActivity, navigationOptions:{header:null}  },

    Mission: { screen: MissionActivity  },

    AvailableService: {screen:AvailableService}

  });
```

Below is the code for AvailableService.js, this exists inside a folder called Modules

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView} from 'react-native';

import {StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import SecondActivity from './SecondActivity';

class AvailableService extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

       super(props);

       const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

       this.state = {

         dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([

               'Item 1',
               'Item 2',
               'Item 3',
               'Item 4',
               'Item 5',
               'Item 6',
               'Item 7',
               'Item 8',
               'Item 9',
               'Item 10',
               'Item 11',
               'Item 12',
               'Item 13',
               'Item 14',
               'Item 15',
               'Item 16',
               'Item 17',
               'Item 18',
               'Item 19',
               'Item 20',
           ]),

       };


     }

     ListViewItemSeparatorLine = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            height: .5,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
          }}
        />
      );
    }

    OpenSecondActivity (rowData)
    {

       this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { ListViewClickItemHolder: rowData });

    }

static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'FirstActivity',
  };


  render()
  {
     return(
        <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

<ListView

           dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

           renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparatorLine}

           renderRow={
                       (rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer} onPress={this.OpenSecondActivity.bind(this, rowData)}>{rowData}</Text>
                     }

         />


        </View>
     );
  }
}



export default Project = StackNavigator(
{
  First: { screen: AvailableService },

  Second: { screen: SecondActivity }
});
```

below is the image from AvailableService

[image]

below is the code for SecondActivity, this also exists inside the module folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView} from 'react-native';

export default class SecondActivity extends Component
{
  static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'SecondActivity',
  };

  render()
  {
     return(
        <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

           <Text style = { styles.TextStyle }> { this.props.navigation.state.params.ListViewClickItemHolder } </Text>

        </View>
     );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
      MainContainer:
      {
         justifyContent: 'center',
         flex:1,
         margin: 10

      },

      TextStyle:
      {
         fontSize: 23,
         textAlign: 'center',
         color: '#000',
      },

      rowViewContainer: 
      {

        fontSize: 18,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,

      }

    });
```

below is the image from secondActivity:

[image]

I am not sure where should I change the code to avoid the double navigaton bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set "headerMone" to none on nested navigator.

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
   Screen: { screen: Screen }
}, {
   headerMode: 'none'
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/141) is similar issue.

Comment: headerMode:none is hiding both the headers. I need at least one header to go back and forth the screens. This is what I did: 
export default Project = StackNavigator(
{
  First: { screen: AvailableService},
 
  
  Second: { screen: SecondActivity}

 
},

{
    headerMode:'none',
 
}

);

Comment: Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: Use AvailableService as StackNavigator with the screen that contains your ListView at first. Then call AvailableService StackNavigator from your MainActivity.

Comment: Can you show me in the example above. I still could not resolve the issue.